# No need of defining hash at the beginning in perl?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

Is there no need of defining perl hash variables at the beginning of the code.

For example, I found in a script a variable "trans" that was not defined as `my %trans` or `%trans` anywhere in the code. But the following codes seemed to be working.

```
$trans{$lang_code} = set_elements($files_to_process{$lang_code},@tags_to_extract);
```

and

```
$test = $trans{lc $Preferred_Language}->{'t_14'};
```

Does Perl interpret "trans" as a hash variable after checking the syntax and proceed?. Is that what happens

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. Among other things, it will specifically forbid you from using global variables by accident.

Comment: Another gotcha, keep in mind that $trans and %trans can coexist, but $trans{'key'} will be a lookup in %trans.

Comment: `$trans` `@trans` and `%trans` can all coexist.  Even sometimes on the same line in a way where you have to scratch your head to tell them apart.  Like: `@trans= split /,/, $trans ;  @trans{@trans}= undef`

Comment: that can be quite confusing. @ikegami & Tom McClure.. got that. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without `use strict`, global variables are created automatically when you use them.  Handy for one line scripts, but generally frowned upon.  Also, keys in hashes are automatically created as well.  You'll see fewer people complaining about code like `$trans{'key1'}{'subkey'}{'detailkey'}{'deepkey'} ++` which creates **key1**, **subkey**, **detailkey** and **deepkey** in each of those hashes if they don't already exist.

Comment: This language feature is called Autovivification - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification

Comment: Yes, there's a feature available `no autovivification ;` but I never see anyone recommend it.

Comment: @woolstar: I've seen `no autovivification;` recommended by several people, but I've never actually used it myself. (Some people consider autovivification to be a problem or misfeature.  I am not one of them.)